# Create a POST header

Tags: javascript, post, extjs, header, request

Here's the thing: I have an array which I must send to another page... not using an AJAX request. I'm trying to redirect my user to this new page, or maybe to open a popup with the new page, but this new page must receive the array data on a POST request.

How do I do this in javascript? I have no problem JSON encoding my array before sending it, I just don't know how to redirect my user to a new page with the data "attached", in javascript.

I'm using ExtJS4, so if there's anything on Ext.util, I have no problem using it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this (using javascript)

- make a new FORM
- set the action as the new page
- set the method as POST
- add a hidden field
- set the value of the field to this Value you want to send
- Pragmatically submit the form

Comment: I'll use this solution for now... but isn't there another way to do it? It sounds like a workaround (and not a very pretty one) :(
It works, though, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [Ajax POST](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) to the target page's url:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'/target/url/', async:false, method:'POST',
    jsonData: {
        jsonArray: yourJsonArray            
    }
    success: function() {
        console.log('posted successfully');
    }
});
```

`async:false` loses the asynchronous functionality; simply remove it if you don't need your POST to be synchronous.

Comment: I need the user to be redirected to said page, not just to access it. The target page will be an excel spreadsheet download page, based on the data the user entered in the previous page. Dispatching an ajax request wouldn't trigger the download.

Comment: @PedroCordeiro If you're not changing the data on the server, i.e. just downloading an Excel doc, than you should just be redirecting with proper GET parameters, and not posting to that URL.

Comment: The information I need to send is too big to send on the URL :(